# Who / what am I?

Tags: riddle, word, english

I can be in many places when you talk, and there is more to me than just intention.

Some say I am bad. I mean, I am... but maybe you will understand that sometimes I am needed for a happy ending.

All things considered, I am just as normal as you can get.

Hint:

> Focus on the last 2 paragraphs. The first sentence confirms the solution, but I realized it might lead you to wrong ideas.

Hint 2:

> Hidden in plain sight

Hint 3:

> "parts of speech"

Comment: Is it "Confidence"?

Comment: @Ajay While I understand that it would fit well in some clues, I cannot see that it would fit all. It's not the answer I meant.

Comment: I was thinking "Karma" in the beginning. Dunno if that serves your purpose

Comment: @Ajay Nope. I also don't see how it would fit all the clues. Also, please note the English tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I think you can be quite

> MEAN

I can be in many places when you talk, and there is more to me than just intention.

> Intention is a synonym for 'meaning' ("What I meant was...")

Some say I am bad. I mean, I am... but maybe you will understand that sometimes I am needed for a happy ending.

> Bad is a synonym for mean. Also the second part is equivalent to the phrase 'a means to an end'. 'Mean' is also hidden in plain sight in this paragraph.

All things considered, I am just as normal as you can get.

> Mean as in the arithmetic average, and average being 'as normal as you can get'.

Taken all together, this explains the first line 'I can be in many places when you talk' since

> 'Mean' is used in the synonyms and phrases outlined above as a verb, an adjective and a noun - a flexible word indeed!

Comment: You got all clues right, congratulations!

Comment: Thanks @cinico - I enjoyed the riddle :) My stats background helped me with the clue that swung it for me! +1

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it fits all the clues but I'll give it a go..

> Colon!

Some say I am bad. I mean, I am... but maybe you will understand that sometimes I am needed for a happy ending.

> Having a bad colon or colon desease. The colon is the last part of the digestive system and is indeed needed for a happy ending(defecation). Happy "ending" could also refer to the rectum. "I mean, I am.." does not fit here(?).

I can be in many places when you talk, and there is more to me than just intention.

> It can be in many places when you talk I believe is self explanatory. The appendix is part of the colon and we're not sure of its purpose, thus it's more to me than just intention. (am I understanding the sentence wrong? English is obviously not my native language).

All things considered, I am just as normal as you can get.

> We all have one

Comment: This has some nice ideas. You are playing with the word in a way similar to what the solution required, but still your guess is completely unrelated and it doesn't fit all the clues. Nice try though.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> An exclamation

I can be in many places when you talk, and there is more to me than just intention.

> Often an excited person will use exclamation marks often to indicate their excitement. (Not completely sure what the second half of the hint means)

Some say I am bad. I mean, I am... but maybe you will understand that sometimes I am needed for a happy ending.

> Some people use exclamation marks too often (think little kids first learning English), and exclamation points are used to often punctuate good results/conclusions

All things considered, I am just as normal as you can get.

> Exclamation points are one of the most common punctuation marks one can use.

Comment: Good try, but it's not correct answer.